# removing an OU from a record on OpenLdap Database

Tags: linux, openldap

I am trying to remove "ou=ABCD" from this ldap record:

```
   # testing@mydomain.net, ABCD, Active, Member, myldapdomain.org
   dn: uid=testing@mydomain.net,ou=ABCD,ou=Active,ou=Member,dc=myldapdomain,dc=org
   uid: testing@mydomain.net
   cn: testing@mydomain.net
   mail: testing@mydomain.net
   mydn: 012348
   middleName: middleName
   sn: McManum
   class: Member
   status: A
   branch: Philadelphia
   securityAnswer: Skippy
   securityQuestion: First pet's name?
   givenName: James
   userPassword:: easdfafy8xUksdeti23MMW1asdfqbl123HBdfa0a9
   objectClass: top1
   objectClass: person
   objectClass: AbcPerson
   objectClass: AbcUser
```

input.ldif

```
  dn: uid=testing@mydomain.net,ou=ABCD,ou=Active,ou=Member,dc=myldapdomain,dc=org
  changetype: modify
```

Executing the following statement :

```
  ldapmodify -v -h localhost -x  -D "cn=admin,dc=myldapdomain,dc=org" -w mypassword -f < input.ldap
```

Getting the following error:

```
  ldap_initialize( ldap://localhost )
  delete :ABCD
  modifying entry "dn:id=testing@mydomain.net,ou=ABCD,ou=Active,ou=Member,dc=myldapdomain,dc=org"
  modify complete
  ldapmodify: Undefined attribute type (17)
  additional info: ABCD: attribute type undefined
```

Comment: That entry doesn't see to have an `ou` attribute and your `ldif` seems to be incomplete.

Comment: If you want to rename an entry's dn, look at `ldapmodrdn`

Comment: No, I need to delete ou=ABCD from this record

Comment: [Have you tried changing the changetype](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/CDS/ag/8.0/Creating_Directory_Entries-LDIF_Update_Statements.html#LDIF_Update_Statements-Deleting_an_Entry_Using_LDIF)?

Comment: I don't see anyway to modify. It looks like I have delete entire record and then add after removing `OU=ABCD`